# Chen’s Theorem with conditional semiprimes

Tags: semiprimes

Chen’s Theorem states that every sufficiently large even integer can be written as the sum of a prime and a prime or a semiprime (the product of two, not necessarily distinct, primes). Let’s consider the case ‘prime + semiprime’.

$$N = p + P2$$

I’m interested in the semiprime-part (P2) of the theorem. Let’s write P2 as:

$$P2 = p_{i}.p_{j}$$

where $p_{i} \le p_{j} < N$

Is it possible to prove that for every sufficiently large even N there is a solution where $p_{i} > (N/2)^{0.5}$?

I found an interesting paper about Chen’s Theorem with small primes.

Cai, Y.C. Chen's Theorem with Small Primes. Acta Math Sinica 18, 597–604 (2002). https://doi.org/10.1007/s101140200168

Cai proved that there is a solution for $N = p + P2$, for $p \ge N^{0.95}$

‘Small’ primes need ‘large’ semiprimes and large semiprimes can, not necessarily must, be written as $p_{i}.p_{j}$, where $p_{i}$ (and so $p_{j}$) are bigger than $(N/2)^{0.5}$

I don’t know if the ‘small prime’ idea helps. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that Chen's theorem has been misstated: Chen proved that every sufficiently large integer can be written as $p+q$ where $p$ is prime and $q$ is *either a prime or the product of two primes*. Sieve methods are unable to distinguish between these two cases.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Greg, thx! I will update my question.

Comment: Another User, thx! I edited my original post. Hopefully it’s more clear now.